# Root cause for my problem when deploying Spacy on AWS lambda (Klayers)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, aws-lambda

I have been following this guide https://towardsdatascience.com/quickstart-spacy-on-aws-lambda-up-and-running-in-10-minutes-e347037a0ef8 to get Spacy up and running on AWS lambda. I have followed the guide step by step but using the latest layers from https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers. When testing I get the following error:

```
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
/opt/python/spacy/util.py:1538: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if val is True or val is 1:
/opt/python/spacy/util.py:1540: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
elif val is None or val is 0:
START RequestId: addae27b-24ac-4137-b191-067deb298022 Version: $LATEST
/opt/python/spacy/util.py:717: UserWarning: [W094] Model 'en_core_web_sm' (2.2.5) specifies an under-constrained spaCy version requirement: >=2.2.2. This can lead to compatibility problems with older versions, or as new spaCy versions are released, because the model may say it's compatible when it's not. Consider changing the "spacy_version" in your meta.json to a version range, with a lower and upper pin. For example: >=3.0.6,<3.1.0
warnings.warn(warn_msg)
[ERROR] OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from /opt/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/config.cfg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 4, in lambda_handler
    nlp = spacy.load("/opt/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5")
  File "/opt/python/spacy/__init__.py", line 50, in load
    return util.load_model(
  File "/opt/python/spacy/util.py", line 326, in load_model
    return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/spacy/util.py", line 390, in load_model_from_path
    config = load_config(config_path, overrides=dict_to_dot(config))
  File "/opt/python/spacy/util.py", line 547, in load_config
    raise IOError(Errors.E053.format(path=config_path, name="config.cfg"))END RequestId: addae27b-24ac-4137-b191-067deb298022
REPORT RequestId: addae27b-24ac-4137-b191-067deb298022  Duration: 5.02 ms   Billed Duration: 6 ms   Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 124 MB Init Duration: 2087.99 ms
```

The very limited information that I have found on when searching this error is that the function might need more memory. I have tried to increase it, but I am unsure if that is the problem.

Additional info when running the function:

```
Init duration
2087.99 ms

Duration
5.02 ms

Billed duration
6 ms

Resources configured
1024 MB

Max memory used
124 MB
```

I have also tried different paths for the model, but the following is the only one not giving me "can't find model", so I would assume it is correct?

Function code:

```
import json
import spacy
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    nlp = spacy.load("/opt/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5")
    doc = nlp("Hello World from spaCy")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(doc.text)
    }
```

Is there anything else that I can try?